# Shopify create customer api is working on postman but not on react native app

Tags: react-native, shopify, shopify-api

I am working on a Shopify React Native app. I am trying to create a new customer with my app. It is working fine on Postman but not working with my app.
app.
I have also setup my private app on shopify and get all the required credentials from there.

I am posting my code here.

```js
let requestdata =
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers:
  {
  'Authorization':'Basic ' + base64.encode('apikey' + ":" + 
      'password'),
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    
 },
 
  body: JSON.stringify({
 "customer": {
   "first_name": "test",
   "last_name": "user",
   "email": "testuser@example.com",
   "phone": "+15154346011",
   "verified_email": true,
   "addresses": [
    {
      "address1": "123 Oak St",
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "province": "ON",
      "phone": "+15154346011",
      "zip": "123 ABC",
      "last_name": "user",
      "first_name": "test",
      "country": "CA"
    }
  ]
}}),
  
};

  fetch('https://apikey:password@domainname/admin/api/2020- 
   04/customers.json', requestdata)
  .then(res => {
   
    console.log("resoponse",JSON.stringify(res))

   this.setState({
    data:res
  })

  
}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log(err)
})
}
```

Here i am also attaching image of response i am getting.
[image]

```js
{
    "type": "default",
    "status": 200,
    "ok": true,
    "headers": {
        "map": {
            "referrer-policy": "origin-when-cross-origin",
            "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
            "x-request-id": "fe78c2cb-1f8e-4cbc-815b-7a9aef11145e",
            "cf-request-id": "0344067c9e00000f82b3286200000001",
            "set-cookie": "_y=5de13f45-35f4-46a9-92f2-502b08a7ab8e; Expires=Fri, 11-Jun-21 08:09:37 GMT; Path=/, request_method=; path=/; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT, _shopify_y=5de13f45-35f4-46a9-92f2-502b08a7ab8e; Expires=Fri, 11-Jun-21 08:09:37 GMT; Path=/",
            "x-shardid": "41",
            "x-shopify-login-required": "true",
            "expect-ct": "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
            "x-dc": "gcp-us-east1,gcp-us-central1,gcp-us-central1",
            "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block; report=/xss-report?source%5Baction%5D=login&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fauth&source%5Bsection%5D=admin&source%5Buuid%5D=fe78c2cb-1f8e-4cbc-815b-7a9aef11145e",
            "x-sorting-hat-podid": "41",
            "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            "x-frame-options": "DENY",
            "x-download-options": "noopen",
            "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
            "date": "Thu, 11 Jun 2020 08:09:37 GMT",
            "nel": "{\"report_to\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"failure_fraction\":0.01,\"success_fraction\":0.0001}, {\"report_to\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"failure_fraction\":0.01,\"success_fraction\":0.0001}",
            "server": "cloudflare",
            "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
            "x-shopify-stage": "production",
            "report-to": "{\"group\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https://monorail-edge.shopifycloud.com/v1/reports/nel/20190325/shopify\"}]}, {\"group\":\"network-errors\",\"max_age\":2592000,\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https://monorail-edge.shopifycloud.com/v1/reports/nel/20190325/shopify\"}]}",
            "cf-cache-status": "DYNAMIC",
            "alt-svc": "h3-27=\":443\"; ma=86400",
            "x-shopid": "27371339818",
            "shopify-auth-mechanisms": "password",
            "content-language": "en",
            "cf-ray": "5a19d9da9dab0f82-MXP",
            "x-sorting-hat-shopid": "27371339818"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://apikey:password@domainname.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login",
    "_bodyInit": {
        "_data": {
            "size": 1323,
            "offset": 0,
            "blobId": "0e0582a6-41ee-4cac-a1c4-b651149cc87f",
            "__collector": {}
        }
    },
    "_bodyBlob": {
        "_data": {
            "size": 1323,
            "offset": 0,
            "blobId": "0e0582a6-41ee-4cac-a1c4-b651149cc87f",
            "__collector": {}
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the response i am getting from postman:

```json
{
    "customer": {
        "id": 3028204847146,
        "email": "testuser@example.com",
        "accepts_marketing": false,
        "created_at": "2020-06-14T15:59:02+05:30",
        "updated_at": "2020-06-14T15:59:02+05:30",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "user",
        "orders_count": 0,
        "state": "disabled",
        "total_spent": "0.00",
        "last_order_id": null,
        "note": null,
        "verified_email": true,
        "multipass_identifier": null,
        "tax_exempt": false,
        "phone": "+15154346011",
        "tags": "",
        "last_order_name": null,
        "currency": "INR",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "id": 3226192674858,
                "customer_id": 3028204847146,
                "first_name": "test",
                "last_name": "user",
                "company": null,
                "address1": "123 Oak St",
                "address2": null,
                "city": "Ottawa",
                "province": "Ontario",
                "country": "Canada",
                "zip": "123 ABC",
                "phone": "+15154346011",
                "name": "test user",
                "province_code": "ON",
                "country_code": "CA",
                "country_name": "Canada",
                "default": true
            }
        ],
        "accepts_marketing_updated_at": "2020-06-14T15:59:02+05:30",
        "marketing_opt_in_level": null,
        "tax_exemptions": [],
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Customer/3028204847146",
        "default_address": {
            "id": 3226192674858,
            "customer_id": 3028204847146,
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "user",
            "company": null,
            "address1": "123 Oak St",
            "address2": null,
            "city": "Ottawa",
            "province": "Ontario",
            "country": "Canada",
            "zip": "123 ABC",
            "phone": "+15154346011",
            "name": "test user",
            "province_code": "ON",
            "country_code": "CA",
            "country_name": "Canada",
            "default": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your screenshot shows `200 ok` response. Add the full response as a code rather than the screenshot.

Comment: Vladimir please check  response

Comment: What is the response in Postman? What do you expect from the response, which you are getting in your react app? As I see, you get a succesful response with your react app.

Comment: @Rene, Please check the response from postman